# Event Based Scheduling for Direct Query Mode

Tags: powershell, rest, powerbi, scheduling

I am using power BI desktop to publish my dataset to the services and later I am going to use those datasets for my paginated report in PBI Report Builder. Please note that my source is Sybase ASE DB and I am using stored procedures to get data into Power BI Desktop.

What I need is to refresh the dataset in Power BI Services based on the event. Now, what is that event is going to be - For example, refresh should be triggered only when my Sybase DB has been updated fully. Also, we need to have an email notification when data refresh is not successfully executed.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into change detection? https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-may-2020-feature-summary/#_CDM

with that you can create a measure which will cause pbi to update, when it sees that the output of the measure changes. something like:

```
last_update_of_data = max(mytable[datetime])
```

regarding sending an email. I'm not aware of any method to make pbi send an email notification. I would suggest using something like Microsoft Power Automate (aka MS flow)